# Can't set the time value on React Datepicker

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

Hello I'm using react-datepicker with date limited by min, max values for time. Everything works as expected using new Date():

```
minTime={new Date().setHours(11)}
maxTime={new Date().setHours(22)}
```

However error occurs once I want to use tomorrows date generated with helper function:

```
  const tomorrow = () => {
    const today = new Date()
    const tomorrow = new Date()
    tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1)

    return tomorrow
}
```

With settings provided below can't change the time.

```
<DatePicker
  name="Datepicker"
  className="table-booking__input"
  selected={booking.date}
  onChange={this.handleDate}
  showTimeSelect
  minDate={tomorrow()}
  timeFormat="HH"
  timeIntervals={60}
  minTime={booking.date.setHours(11)}
  maxTime={booking.date.setHours(22)}
  dateFormat="MMMM dd, yyyy h aa"
  timeCaption="Time"
  placeholderText="Click and choose the date"
/>
```

Here is my state and handling function:

```
this.state = {
  booking: {
    date: tomorrow(),
    people: 1,
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'jdoe@gty.xx'
  }
}


  handleDate(e) {
    const booking = { ...this.state.booking }
    booking.date = e
    this.setState({ booking })
  }
```

Comment: What error are your experiencing?

Comment: There is no error in web browser console or terminal. When I set the minTime and maxTime equals to "tomorrow.setHours(11)/tomorrow.setHours(22)" instead of 'new Date().setHours(11)/new Date().setHours(22)'. Then Datepicker won't update the time with given user input.